# Rotating a camera about its own axes in three.js

Tags: three.js

Are there examples I can borrow from regarding rotating a camera around its own X, Y and Z axes?  I learned yesterday that I can use the `translate(X|Y|Z)` methods to move a camera along its own axes.  Are there equivalents for rotation as well?

Comment: One would have to know the API for the camera, and it's likely that the documentation for the API already has examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the development version ( three.js r58dev ), a new function has been added for rotating an object on it's own axis:

```
Object3D.rotateOnAxis( axis, angle );
```

`axis` must be a unit-length `Vector3`, and `angle` is in radians.

three.js r58dev